# wso2 identity server: lock account is not working for my custom domain

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Dears,

I have configured a custom user store and mapped additional attributes from my custom DB table to local claims. The new domain called CUSTOMER domain. I'm able to login successfully(screenshot 1, example user: CUSTOMER/10900000).

I have enable lock account under identity provider section in wso2 console, but it's not not working as expected in 5.11 for my custom DOMAIN, for  example a given user is not locked on 3 wrong attempts as expected, I'm getting following error, whereas for PRIMARY domain the admin is getting locked successfully.

Please could you support in solving lock account for my custom domain?

Config: Userstore manager that extends UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager :
`org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore`

Account lock local claims mapped to Primary and to CUSTOMER DOMAIN:

```
  accountLocked
  Failed Login Attempts 
  Account State 
  Failed Lockout Count
  failed Password Recovery Attempts 
  Last Logon Time 
  Locked Reason 
  Unlock Time
```

PFB postman error and audit logs shown on using wrong password for login:

Error:

```
{
    "error_description": "Error when handling event : POST_AUTHENTICATION",
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Carbon logs showing additional debug logs from my overwritten methods:

```
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - doAuthenticateWithUserName starts
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} -  getPasswordFromCredentials...
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.utils.MobileSSOPasswordUtil} -  ################Inside verify hashpassword ######## for@PassW0rd0
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - doAuthenticateWithUserName ends
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - getUserPropertyValuesWithID starts userID=346901 propertyNames=[unlockTime] profileName= default
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - getUserPropertyValuesWithID ends, map={unlockTime=0}
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - getUserPropertyValuesWithID starts userID=346901 propertyNames=[accountLock] profileName= default
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - getUserPropertyValuesWithID ends, map={accountLock=false}
INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - getUserPropertyValuesWithID starts userID=346901 propertyNames=[failedLockoutCount, accountLock, failedLoginAttempts] profileName= default
 INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - getUserPropertyValuesWithID propertyNamesSorted=[accountLock, failedLockoutCount, failedLoginAttempts]
 INFO {org.wso2.emkan.user.store.manager.SecondaryCustomUserStore} - getUserPropertyValuesWithID ends, map={failedLockoutCount=0, accountLock=false, failedLoginAttempts=3}
```

Audit logs:

```
WARN {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Authentication Target=CUSTOMER/10900000 Data=null Outcome=Failure Error={"Error Message":"Un-expected error while authenticating","Error Code":"31001"}
 INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Values Target=CUSTOMER/10900000 Data={"Claims":{"http://wso2.org/claims/identity/unlockTime":"0"},"Profile":"default"} Outcome=Success
 INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Values Target=CUSTOMER/10900000 Data={"Claims":{"http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked":"false"},"Profile":"default"} Outcome=Success
 INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Values Target=CUSTOMER/10900000 Data={"Claims":{"http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts":"3","http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked":"false","http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginLockoutCount":"0"},"Profile":"default"} Outcome=Success
 WARN {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Authentication Target=CUSTOMER/10900000 Data=null Outcome=Failure Error={"Error Message":"TUn-expected error while post-authentication, Error when handling event : POST_AUTHENTICATION","Error Code":"31004"}
 INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : CUSTOMER/10900000 | Action : PostTokenIssue | Target : PasswordGrantAuditLogger | Data : { "AuthenticatedUser" : "N/A","AuthenticatedUserStoreDomain" : "N/A","AuthenticatedUserTenantDomain" : "N/A","ServiceProvider" : "customer new","RequestType" : "oidc","RelyingParty" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" } | Result : Failed
```

[image: lock account local claims config]

[image: successful login]

[image: login using wrong password here]

Comment: Do you see any carbon logs printed in this case? Also, mention the userstore manager type that you use to manage CUSTOMER secondary userstore. In addition can you add the configuration of Account Lock local claim in your IS setup

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I updated the question mentioning custom userstore manager type which extends UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager. Note that login is working, but lock account is not. I have mentioned as well lock account claims mapped to my new Domain CUSTOMER.

Comment: Are you using the default identity store configured in the server or have you configured to store identity claims in userstore (as in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/dialects/configure-claims/)?

Comment: I'm using default identity store configure in the server. I configured Oracle JDBC connection for wso2 database (identity , shared DB)

Answer (score 0):

Im able to test lock account successfully on my custom user store.
I fixed the queries in custom.xml in secondary store, make sure to point to my custom tables, and then I'm able to list users in console as show below:

[image]